# How to define TypeScript generic type that accepts concrete (non-abstract) types only?

Tags: typescript, generics, abstract-class, abstract

I have the following code to register custom elements:

```
class Base extends HTMLElement {

    static register<T extends typeof Base>(type: T) {
        // Other code
        customElements.define("custom", type);
    }

}

class Impl extends Base {

    static register() {
        Base.register(this);
    }

}
```

This works fine until I add `abstract` to `Base`:

```
abstract class Base extends HTMLElement {

    abstract doSomething(): void;

    static register<T extends typeof Base>(type: T) {
        // Other code
        customElements.define("custom", type);
    }

}
```

Error at using `type`:

```
Argument of type 'T' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CustomElementConstructor'.

 Type 'typeof Base' is not assignable to type 'CustomElementConstructor'.

  Cannot assign an abstract constructor type to a non-abstract constructor type.
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgQmgpgnAHhDgHYAmGAEgCoCyAMgKLI4C2piA3gFDcL8JQkGPARkA9gGVx7CAAsAliQDmACgCUALgQA3cQrIBuXgISRgEBbARQcyhZBxQAPNXxFSFBBACeABxxxADMsXAA+VV8A7Wp1BB5TUwB6JIQAeXknJHEyHD5E-lgAV0gZZjYOMAA6XKClHFUAImLS1kaAGm9-HHVjUwBfXkHuFDQMAElWP2R3YnIMbDA8Hnz+CWlZRRUNeIRh03NLa1t7RygdhILQpaqTh2Jz+Qde1b2hoA)

How do I declare that `T` must be concrete (non-abstract) class only so I can use it that way? Thanks.